# add/delete dns entries in a bind dns server zones using dnsjava

Tags: java, dns, bind, dnsjava

I searched a lot but I didn't find a clear answer. My goal is to make java methods that can add and delete dns entries from a dns server. I installed and configured bind9 dns server on a debian VM. I'm using dnsjava library. I can read from the dns server the zones and records and all of it and I can also send updates that are being received but the response is SERVFAIL.As a result I can't change the dns server's zones like adding and removing records although I configured them by allowing updates.
Can anyone help me to proceed?

Comment: Did you get the solution ?